# Solspace Calendar ICS Export

Tags: solspace, calendar

I've added the exp:calendar:ics_export code found here (https://solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/docs/ics-export/), set my date parameters, and tried to add category="34" to only export items from that category, but all calendar items are still exporting. Is there another way to only e?

Answer (score 1):

Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem.